# "no real work" vs "not any real work"

Tags: grammar

I saw this test in a grammar book: which word or phrase best completes the following sentence?

> ..... real work was done in the office while the boss was away.
>
> a) Not a
>
> b) Not any
>
> c) No
>
> d) None

The answer according to the book is **no**, which is obviously correct. But it seems to me that the sentence is also grammatical with **not any**. I'd like to know that if **not any** can't be the correct answer here, why is it so?

Comment: To me "Not any" is wrong because it sounds wrong. I will leave it to a grammarian to say whether it's grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Because "Not any" would be used with a countable quantity, so it is not correct with work, which is not a countable noun. "Not any people, not one goose, not a single book, and no real work."

Comment: @EthanBolker, It sounds completely correct to me! But my intuition can't be trusted here, because I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

the use of "not any" seems awkward to me. "Not any" is not usually used at the start of a sentence in this way. Note that [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+Not+any%2C+_START_+No&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_START_%20Not%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20No%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C_START_%20Not%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20No%3B%2Cc0) shows essentially zero use of "Not any" at the start of a sentence.

To come at this another way, let us consider altering the sentence.

The sentence suggested by the book is:

> No real work was done in the office while the boss was away.

If we want to change this to indicate that soem work was done, we can easily create:

> Some real work was done in the office while the boss was away.

and that is a perfectly valid and natural sentence.  But suppose we want to make a similar change to the version that starts with "Not any". then the sentence:

> No real work was done in the office while the boss was away.

> Not any real work was done in the office while the boss was away.

becomes:

> Any real work was done in the office while the boss was away.

this is pretty clearly not natural, and I suspect not even grammatical. This helps show that "not any" cannot be a valid answer to the question in the book.

Answer (score 0):

“Not any” is a perfectly idiomatic intensifier of “no” (at least in American English). Nor is there a grammatical issue. Some may consider “not any” somewhat informal. I do not.

> There was not any evidence of fraud

is just more emphatic than

> There was no evidence of fraud

Comment: But that's in the predicate. Can you find any examples of _not any_ in the subject? I think they're much rarer.

Comment: Yes, but surely we never begin a sentence with _Not any_?  _There was not any evidence of fraud_ is OK, but no-one would say _Not any evidence of fraud was found_.

Comment: -1 @Kate Bunting is correct. See the Ngram in my answer. The example with "not any" in the middle of the sentence, modifying the object , is not comparable to the use of "Not any" at the start, modifying the subject.

Comment: “Not any evidence of forced entry was found at the scene of the crime” is a perfectly good sentence.

Comment: I don't find it at all idiomatic.